# What are the components of this sensor?

Tags: identification, components, transducer

[image]Attached is a schematic that looks like an accelerator or a combo sensor with plenty of inputs/output. Can you please assist in helping point out the pull up resistors, voltage regulator, and any significant component? I know the basic passive components, however the there are a few pull up resistors that complement the open-drain lines and a voltage regulator that I am interested in finding.

Comment: The question is a bit puzzling. Pull-ups pull up to the positive supply and should be very obvious to you. There are only two chips one of which is the voltage regulator. Is this homework that you can't figure out? If so, you need to show some work.

Comment: I assumed the chip with (capacitors c1-c5) is the voltage regulator thank you for pointing it out. And r1-r6 are the pull up resistors?  Yes this is a homework assignment, however my work was described in my question as i needed to describe all the component and their functionality. The voltage regulator is needed to lower the voltage from the source to the chip because the chip probably requires less voltage to operate.

Comment: We don't do guessing games here.  While the role of the interconnection including the FETs is clear, as a matter of courtesy and efficiency you should identify the sensor IC and explain where you got the schematic.

Comment: My professor provided the circuit as a practice exam for our final. Please don't take my word ("assumed") as part of a guessing name or uncertainty level. The context speaks for itself- I was clearly clarifying.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 2):

The SPI interface has the master on the source side (left) and multiple slaves on the right.

The FETs serve as bidirectional open drain nodes for active low communication.

There are  I2C and I3C duplex protocols supported with SPI.

https://www.microcontrollertips.com/improved-inter-integrated-circuit-i3c/

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please assist in helping point out the pull up resistors, voltage regulator, and any significant component?

You seem to have figured out most of it in the comments but here are a few pointers.

Note that the top circuit has a device with an IN and an OUT and that IN is connecded to V<sub>IN</sub> and OUT is connected to V<sub>DD</sub>. If the output is connected to a voltage rail then it must be a voltage regulator. Since this circuit has no inductors which would be required for a voltage boosting circuit we can assume that V<sub>DD</sub> < V<sub>IN</sub> and that both are positive. The capacitors are there to filter out noise and keep the regulator from oscillating.

Pull-up resistors always pull up and all six resistor are connected to positive supplies so all six are pulling up.
Notice that R5 and R6 are pulling up to the V<sub>IN</sub> rail which we've already decided is a higher voltage than the V<sub>DD</sub> rail. We can therefore assume that Q1 and Q2 are being used as level shifters to reduce the voltage on SDA and SCL lines on the 9-pin connector before going into the chip on the left. Most likely this means that the external circuit is using 5 V logic and this circuit is using 3.3 V logic.